# Override methods in parallel class hierarchies

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

Which are my options to fix the issues with parallel inheritance hierarchies below? I would like to keep the Serializer classes stateless.

```
public abstract class BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Boolean SortComponents { get; set; }
}

public class TextSerializerOptions : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Int32 TrimStrings { get; set; }
}

public class BinarySerializerOptions : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Boolean SkipNulls { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseSerializer
{
    public abstract void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, BaseSerializerOptions opt);
}

public class TextSerializer : BaseSerializer
{
    public override void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, TextSerializerOptions opt)
    {
    }
}

public class BinarySerializer : BaseSerializer
{
    public override void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, BinarySerializerOptions opt)
    {
    }
}
```

I would like to be able to write methods like this:

```
    static void Test(BaseSerializer s, BaseSerializerOptions o)
    {
        var obj = new MyObject { ... };
        using (var f = File.OpenWrite("..."))
        {
            s.Serialize(obj, f, o);
        }
        // do more things here to check the serializer result; 
        // the serializers might return some kind of operation status, which I want to check
    }

    static void TestSerializers()
    {
        Test(new TextSerializer(), new TextSerializerOptions {...});
        Test(new BinarySerializer(), new BinarySerializerOptions {...});
    }
```

Comment: How about `class BaseSerializer<T> where T : BaseSerializerOptions { public abstract void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, T opt); }`?

Comment: I think you just don't need a `BaseSerializer`, because it is pretty unclear how you are going to use it with generic options. I personally would either: 1. Remove `BaseSerializer` at all and use specific serializers for specific tasks. 2. Move `options` to a constructor of specific serializers, replace `BaseSerializer` with `ISerializer` with `Serializer(object obj, Stream s)` method.

Comment: Both suggestions look good, please post a full answer to make it more clear to the author

Comment: @opewix, the second suggestion is not according to what I want; I want to keep the `Serializer` classes statless; I do not want to keep the options as state inside the serializers.

Comment: the first suggestion is also not very helpful; I can't use the `BaseSerializer<T>` class as a normal abstract base class, since it depends on a concrete options class.

Comment: @AndreiBozantan Do you mean you can't compile it or it doesn't fit good to your code?

Comment: @opewix I mean that I want to be able to write: `void TestSerialize(BaseSerializer s, BaseSerializerOptions o) { var obj = new MyObject { ... }; s.Serialize(obj, stream, o); }` and neither of the suggestions will help me.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev I added a sample in order to understand how I thought to use the `BaseSerializer`.

Comment: @AndreiBozantan see edit in my post, there is a new example

Comment: Since I was not happy with the suggestions, I thought more about the issue and I found myself another solution to this. Basically I give up to the inheritance hierarchy involving the `Serializer` classes and I replace it with static methods. The polymorphic behavior is achieved using the inheritance chain based on the `BaseSerializerOptions` class.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the first suggestion in the comments:

```
public abstract class BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Boolean SortComponents { get; set; }
}

public class TextSerializerOptions : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Int32 TrimStrings { get; set; }
}

public class BinarySerializerOptions : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Boolean SkipNulls { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseSerializer<T> where T : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public abstract void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, T opt);
}

public class TextSerializer : BaseSerializer<TextSerializerOptions>
{
    public override void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, TextSerializerOptions opt)
    {
    }
}

public class BinarySerializer : BaseSerializer<BinarySerializerOptions>
{
    public override void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, BinarySerializerOptions opt)
    {
    }
}
```

Update for specific syntax usage:

```
public class TextSerializer : BaseSerializer
{
    public void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, TextSerializerOptions opt)
    {
        this.Serialize(obj, s, opt);
    }

    public override void Serialize(object obj, Stream s, BaseSerializerOptions opt)
    {
        if (opt is TextSerializerOptions options)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}

public class BinarySerializer : BaseSerializer
{
    public void Serialize(Object obj, Stream s, BinarySerializerOptions opt)
    {
        this.Serialize(obj, s, opt);
    }

    public override void Serialize(object obj, Stream s, BaseSerializerOptions opt)
    {
        if (opt is BinarySerializerOptions options)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years ago I had the opportunity to learn a little bit about functional programming, using Haskell, and most of the FP concepts seemed really intuitive to me. Since I was not happy with the suggestions for my questions, I had the really good idea to ask myself: How I will do this in Haskell? So, below is my solution to this, inspired by thinking from a FP perspective.  Basically I give up to one of the inheritance hierarchies (the ones with the serializer classes), and I use static methods instead. Functional programming makes me a better OOP programmer... true story!

```
public abstract class BaseSerializerOptions
{
    Boolean SortComponents { get; set; }
}

public class TextSerializerOptions : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Boolean TrimStrings { get; set; }
}

public class BinarySerializerOptions : BaseSerializerOptions
{
    public Boolean SkipNulls { get; set; }
}

public class SerializerResult
{

}

public static class Serializer
{
    public static SerializerResult Write(Object obj, Stream s, BaseSerializerOptions opt)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
            case TextSerializerOptions o: return WriteText(obj, s, o);
            case BinarySerializerOptions o: return WriteBinary(obj, s, o);
        }
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static SerializerResult WriteText(Object obj, Stream s, TextSerializerOptions opt)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static SerializerResult WriteBinary(Object obj, Stream s, BinarySerializerOptions opt)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Test(BaseSerializerOptions o)
    {
        var obj = new Object();

        using (var fs = File.Open("...", FileMode.Create))
        {
            var r1 = Serializer.Write(obj, fs, o);
            CheckSerializerResults(r1);
        }
    }

    static void TestSerializers()
    {
        Test(new TextSerializerOptions { TrimStrings = true });
        Test(new BinarySerializerOptions { SkipNulls = false });
    }

    static void CheckSerializerResults(SerializerResult r)
    {

    }
}
```